# Boots and Movement Speed

Tags: league-of-legends

How many Percent of movement speed boots offer? By example, Boots have movement what varies between 1 and 5. What If in late game I want replacing a boot that gives "Movement 2" with another item with movement speed equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Accurate as of May 2013**

Boots underwent a big change during the preseason 3 patch.

- Boots no longer list a "Movement 1" type speed, but instead grant a specific flat movement speed.
- All champions had their base movement speeds increased by 25
- The movement speed bonus of all boots was reduced by 25.
- Boots can now be upgraded with one of five [Enchantments](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Enchantment), one of which grants a flat +15 movement speed bonus.

The changes were made to de-emphasize the necessity of starting with boots at level 1, and give boots more endgame utility.

### Current Boot Movement Speeds

- +25 movement speed - [Boots of Speed](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Boots_of_Speed)
- +45 movement speed - [Berserker's Greaves](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Berserker%27s_Greaves), [Sorcerer's Shoes](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sorcerer%27s_Shoes), [Ionian Boots of Lucidity](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ionian_Boots_of_Lucidity), [Ninja Tabi](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ninja_Tabi), [Mercury's Treads](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mercury%27s_Treads), [Boots of Mobility (in combat)](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Boots_of_Mobility)
- +60 Movement Speed - [Boots of Swiftness](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Boots_of_Swiftness)
- +105 Movement Speed - [Boots of Mobility (out of combat)](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Boots_of_Mobility)

### Replacing your boots with a percentage movement speed item

Occasionally you're tempted to replace your boots late-game with a damage item that grants percentage movement speed instead. This happens a lot less frequently than it used to, due to the ability to Enchant your boots to grant additional abilities.  That said, lets look at the math below:

The [movement speed mechanics](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Movement_speed) state that:

> (Base Movement Speed + Flat Movement Bonuses) × (1 + Percentage Movement Bonuses) × (Slow Ratio × Slow Resist Ratio)

Given this, lets say you had +45 flat movement speed boots, and you want to know if you can replace the boots with a percentage movement speed item, while still maintaining roughly the same speed you had before.

As an example, lets say you're one of the fastest champions in the game, Pantheon, with a base movement speed of 355.  You're facing off against a team that mostly has base movement speeds of 345 (Xin Zhao for example).  Nobody seems to be running movement speed quintessences.

#### Pantheon with +45 movement speed boots

> (355+45)*(1+0) = 400 Movement Speed

#### Xin Zhao with +45 movement speed boots

> (345+45)*(1+0) = 390 Movement Speed

Initially, you'll run faster than Xin, and given your W gap closer, you can easily chase him down and initiate.  Even with his E gap closer, he'll have a hard time catching you to initiate.

What if Pantheon replaces his boots with a Zephyr (10% movement speed)?

#### Pantheon with Zephyr

> (355+0)*(1+.1) = 390.5 Movement Speed

In this case, your movement speed falls to almost exactly the same as Xin, and you're now evenly matched.  This may be useful if you have an ally initiating, and you need the offensive stats on Zephyr to give your team the extra damage.  However, if Pantheon is the one initiating, you're now going to have a harder time doing so, and will have to rely on your ult, or other tricks to close the gap.

Of course, what happens if Xin Enchants his boots for +15 movement speed, or he's running 4.5% movement speed quintessences, or both?  He's going to be at 423 movement speed, and you're going to be unable to chase him down without boots of your own.

Answer (score 6):

Boots give a flat speed bonus. It's not a percentage, like other items. As such, the percentages to make up for losing boots will be different depending on the base speed of your current hero.

Enhanced Movement x on boots will increase movement speed by 30 + 20x. For example, Enhanced Movement 1 will increase speed by 50, and Enhanced Movement 5 will increase speed by 130.

Answer (score 3):

They don't increase it by a given percentage but by a flat Value:

- Movement 1: 50
- Movement 2: 70
- Movement 3: 90
- Movement 5: 130